# Why is the submit button on my contact form not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So we have this contact form in the footer of a web page that does not work, the form validation and jquery events arent connected with the form itself.

The javascript on the page should be attaching an event to the submit button, but it looks like this isn't working.

Here is the jQuery:

```js
                jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
                    jQuery('#form_contact_form_widget_001').validationEngine('init');

                    jQuery('#form_contact_form_widget_001 a#contact_form_widget_001_wformsend').click(function () { 
                        var form_builder_url = jQuery('#contact_form_widget_001_wurl').val();

                        jQuery('#form_contact_form_widget_001 .loading').animate( {
                            opacity : 1
                        } , 250);

                        if (jQuery('#form_contact_form_widget_001').validationEngine('validate')) { 
                            jQuery.post(form_builder_url, { 
                                field_003 : jQuery('#field_003').val(), 
                                field_004 : jQuery('#field_004').val(), 
                                formname : 'contact_form_widget_001', 
                                formtype : 'widget' 
                            }, function () { 
                                jQuery('#form_contact_form_widget_001 .loading').animate( { opacity : 0 }, 250);
                                document.getElementById('form_contact_form_widget_001').reset();
                                jQuery('#form_contact_form_widget_001').parent().find('.widgetinfo').hide();
                                jQuery('#form_contact_form_widget_001').parent().find('.widgetinfo').fadeIn('fast');
                                jQuery('html, body').animate( { scrollTop : (jQuery('#form_contact_form_widget_001').offset().top - 100) }, 'slow');
                                jQuery('#form_contact_form_widget_001').parent().find('.widgetinfo').delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
                            } );

                            return false;
                        } else { 
                            jQuery('#form_contact_form_widget_001 .loading').animate( { opacity : 0 }, 250);

                            return false;
                        }
                    } );
                } );
```

Any ideas why this isn't working properly?

http://medicure-html.cmsmasters.net/

This template page has a working version of the same form.

Comment: You have to fix error before: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined` Check your console

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the html source, you have this for your form:

There is no action defined other than "#", should at least have a page url or function in it.

Comment: OP is binding click event on element, at least he tries

Comment: I don't think this is the issue here. http://medicure-html.cmsmasters.net/  this template page uses the same code and the form is working properly because there is an event attached to the submit button. I haven't been able to figure out why the event is not attached on my version.

Comment: @GLevy124 Don't expect any site containing any js error to work properly

Answer (score 0):

you want to use jQuery's built in `submit` event for your form.

In order to override the default form behavior you should pass in an event object `e` into this event and call `e.preventDefault()`. This will stop your form from jumping to the top of the screen and failing to preform your action.

```
jQuery('#form_contact_form_widget_001').submit(function (e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  // rest of the code
});
```